# how to check if std::span has the required layout at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to check at compile time if std::span has a specific layout. The code below is what I've got so far. It doesn't work.

```
#include<bit>
#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>
#include<span>
#include<type_traits>
#include<vector>

template<typename T>
struct MySpan {
    T* data;
    std::size_t size;
};

int main() {

    assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<MySpan<int>>);
    assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<std::span<int>>);
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::span const sp{ v };

    auto const mySpan = std::bit_cast<MySpan<int>>(sp);

    assert(sp.data() == mySpan.data);
    assert(sp.size() == mySpan.size);
    assert(sizeof(sp) == sizeof(mySpan));
    constexpr bool layoutCompat = std::is_layout_compatible_v<std::span<int>, MySpan<int>>;
    assert(layoutCompat); // assertion failed, why?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```cpp
std::is_layout_compatible_v<std::span<int>, MySpan<int>>;
```

Should evaluate as `true` with MSVC's implementation. It does lay out the fields in that order. That fact that it does not is an MSVC bug, which I reported [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1960) and then Casey Carter moved to [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/1442026).

Casey's reduced version of my example from the test case there is (but rewritten by me to avoid using the compiler intrinsic):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct B { int x; };
class D : public B {};

static_assert(std::is_layout_compatible_v<D, B>);
```

This should be valid (`B` and `D` *are* layout-compatible), but the compiler currently rejects this. This is the same thing that's causing the original `span` check to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Without reflection, there is no mechanism you can use to determine the layout of a type. You can test layout compatibility, but you cannot determine the layout itself. That is, if they're not layout compatible, you can't determine *why* they aren't.

Maybe that `span` implementation puts the size first. Maybe the size is in a base class subobject which can be empty when the size is static. Who knows.

You cannot write code to `bit_cast` a `span`. Not code that works across implementations, anyway. And really, there's no point in doing so. You can just give your type the ability to construct itself from an existing `span`. `bit_cast` is returning a new object anyway, so it's not like it's going to be faster or something.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce OP's failure on the latest MSVC, and have manually confirmed that both types (at least in my test), are in fact the exact same types in the exact same order.